# Which is correct - 'Do you bought pizza last night' OR 'Did you buy pizza last night'?

Tags: tense, grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs

Do you bought pizza last night OR Did you buy pizza last night?

When we can say "do you bought" instead of saying "did you buy"? or just a half an hour ago?

Comment: Maybe you mean to ask, would it be correct, "Have you bought a pizza last night?" "Do you bought a pizza?" is quite ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4):

"Do you bought" is incorrect. "Did you buy" is the correct way to form a question in the past tense.

Questions in English can be formed by switching the order of the subject and the [helping verb](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/Helping-Verbs.html). For a sentence like "You bought...", which doesn't have a helping verb, a form of the verb "do" is used, with the infinitive of the verb. The question is formed as follows:

You bought... -> You did buy... -> Did you buy...?

The forms *"you do bought" and *"do you bought" are not used in Standard English.

Note that "Have you bought a pizza last night." is problematic, as it combines a *present* perfect, with a time expression indicating the *past*

Comment: You say "have bought last night" is problematic, but can you also explain in what way? Is it grammatically incorrect, can it cause confusion etc? Would "Have you bought a pizza this week" be less problematic?

Comment: It would indeed be less problematic. The present perfect is, in most cases, not suited to be used for a past event that already ended on a fixed date (here, *last night*).

Answer (score 1):

Did you buy pizza last night is the perfect and grammatical one. Because it involves the past tense or means that things has already been occurred but do you bought... It's in correct because the word  "do" it self involves things that are currently happening at the moment example Do you trust me, Do you go to church, Do you love God. Etc